# Solr - Java heap space tuning for Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, solr5, sitecore8.2

In our Sitecore 8.2 installation we use Solr 5.1.0 as an indexing system.
Recently we have had some issues like this:

> [sitecore_analytics_index] org.apache.solr.common.SolrException;
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
>   Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: this
>   IndexWriter is closed
>   **Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

What is the correct way to choose the heap threshold to give to Solr?

At the moment, among the different cores, the only one that exceeds a few hundred megabytes is `sitecore_analytics_index` which has a size of 32.67 GB and these features:

- Num Docs: 102015908
- Max Doc: 105114766
- Heap Memory Usage: -1
- Deleted Docs: 3098858
- Version: 5563749
- Impl:org.apache.solr.core.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory
- org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory:​NRTCachingDirectory(lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@​2e51764c;maxCacheMB=48.0
  maxMergeSizeMB=4.0)

The server has 6 GB of RAM, 4 GB of which dedicated to Java, below some args of the JVM:

-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps-XX:+PrintGCDetails-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC-XX:+UseParNewGC-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50-XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=6000-XX:ConcGCThreads=4-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8-XX:NewRatio=3-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4-XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=64m-XX:SurvivorRatio=4-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90-Xms4G-Xmx4G-Xss256k-verbose:gc

Based on this amount of data, which is the correct configuration of the heap?

Answer (score 1):

The right amount of memory allocation to JVM should be between 6 and 12 GB out of 8-16 GB dedicated to the server.

You already have a large analytics index and with time it will grow even more, therefore, you will keep experience the high memory utilisation due to the high amount of index write and commit operations. I would recommend you to consider sharding your big indexes or using SolrCloud which is under Experimental Support for your Sitecore version 8.2, read more [here](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897).